# AWS Lambda 'full' vs 'incremental' cold start?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm looking into cold start issues and have the impression that there's a difference between:

- a 'full' cold start, i.e. going from 0 to 1 active instance
- an 'incremental' cold start, i.e. going from n to n+1 active instances

It's rather difficult to accurately test the 'incremental' scenario though.

Can anybody confirm my impression, and possibly explain why there's a difference?

Comment: Where are you seeing that there is a difference in these two scenarios?

Comment: That's why I say it's an "impression". I find it rather hard to test this accurately. So far, I've only seen long delays after a period of inactivity, not when there's a lot of activity - even though from time to time, extra instances should be started then. But what I'm really after is understanding cold start behavior, so if you know/believe my impression must be false, I'll be happy to hear!

Comment: Which language are you using? It's normally only Java people who are impacted by the startup time of a Lambda container.

Comment: Language is node. Execution time for a cold start would be e.g. 4s, compared to 1s normally. Not as high as with Java, but too high for interactive scenarios and problematic in case one cold lambda may call another cold lambda...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is no instance with your Lambda in its memory, AWS does not know that an instance will be needed, that's why the first cold start takes longer. If your Lambda is already under load, AWS can predict a new instance will be needed. So it prepares a new instance upfront, after that requests are distributed to that instance. Therefore your observation is correct, cold start is an issue only for functions with zero activity.

Comment: That sounds like a very reasonable explanation, thanks! Just being curious: do you *know* it's like this or do you go by your own reasoning/observation?

Comment: I drew this conclusion after a lot of load testing. Not confirmed by AWS though.

Comment: Not true. Try a script that shouts say 10 requests simultaneously say with Jmeter. On my experiments first and second request duration the difference my increase, then it stabilizes.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to test, write a Jmeter test and shoot requests with little delay (50 ms). Repeat after several hours of inactivity. Probably best to leave it run for a weekend On my tests the duration of the cold start increases then stabilize (though I used python with some heavy web frameworks and zappa). If needed add logs.